# How are domestic microwave oven magnetron ring magnets constructed?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

I use the ring magnets from the magnetrons in microwave ovens for various purposes and discovered that one face of the magnets attracts an iron bar more strongly than the other. I assumed that the rings are simple ferrite magnets magnetised with one pole on one face, the other on the reverse. If that were so, why should the magnetic strength of the two faces differ?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an insulating or nonmetallic layer on the "weak" side?

Comment: I don't know about magnetron magnets, but a permanent magnet does not necessarily need to have just one "north" pole and just one "south" pole that are geometrically opposite each other. (see, https://www.arborsci.com/products/multipole-neodymium-super-ring-magnet) The poles do have to come in pairs, but depending on how they are arranged, it is possible for one "face" of a magnet to be much more strongly attracted to nearby ferrous metal than some other face. (see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array)

Comment: The magnets look quite homogenous, I don't want to waste one by breaking it up! The Halbach Array idea looks more interesting, it would make sense to maximise the flux within the magnetron tube this way. Does anyone know who makes them?

Comment: The field in a circular Halbach array is in the plane perpendicular to the axis, in a magnetron the field is parallel with the axis.

Comment: So it's not that then.

Comment: Investigating the 6 ring magnets I have again today one showed equal attraction for both faces, the rest of the larger ones 65gm one face 135gm the other at a distance of 18mm, but some were stronger on the N face some on the South. Unfortunately I didn't note their pairing before I dismantled the assemblies. Then I tried an old horseshoe magnet and found that the N pole attracted a piece of iron (that wasn't itself magnetised) much more strongly to the N pole than the South. I remain puzzled.